# Get objects assigned to ForeignKey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

to be honest im not pretty sure how to explain this but i want to display all objects assigned to foreignkey when im in one of this objects

### MODELS.PY

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    ...
    name =  models.CharField(max_length=267)
    CategoryThumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

```py
class Video(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    ...
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    nazwa = models.CharField(max_length=267)
    embedlink = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    thumbnail = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
```

### VIEWS.PY

```py
def Category(request, slug):
    category_user = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    category_video = Video.objects.filter(Category = category_user)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    dict = {'category_user' : category_user, 'category_video' : category_video, 'categories' : categories}
    return render(request, 'categories.html', dict)

def video(request, id):
    video_user = Video.objects.get(pk=id)
    videos = Video.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    dict = {'video_user' : video_user, 'categories' : categories, 'videos': videos}
    return render(request, 'video.html', dict)
```

### TEMPLATE categories.html

```html
                {% for video in category_video %} {% if category_video %}
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div class="between">
                        <a href="/video/{{ video.id }}"><img loading="lazy" id="resize" src="{{ video.thumbnail }}.png" class="miniimg"></a>
                        <figcaption class="caption"><a style="color: #ffffff; font-size: 17px; font-weight: bold;" href="/video/{{ video.id }}"> {{ video.name }} </a></figcaption>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %} {% endfor %}
```

To this moment everything works but when i want to display objects from video in category
but when im trying to display Video Objects that are assigned to the Category in Video Template it doesnt work no matter what i do. I'm trying to do it about half a year and no results my video.html changed a lot of times to make it so ill not put code from here. I'll include photo to better understand(rectangles are same videos). To sum up I want to display same elements assigned to foreignkey in category and when i open element.
[IMAGE DESCRIPTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dT5hI.png)
1.Is on the Category HTML
2.On Video HTML

Comment: Do I understand your question correctly, in your template, for any given category, you want to display all videos that are linked to that category?

Comment: no no, I want to something like website with serials where u can pick episode in category page(e.g video.com/strangerthings/) and after instead of coming back to previous url(e.g video.com/strangerthings/)  to change episode do it on the same url (e.g video.com/strangerthings/episode/1). something like playlists on youtube when u view playlist and when u play something on it that playlist displays on right side. how i said its hard to explain for. @iri

Answer (score 1):

I strongly advise you to back to the document to read about ForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

anyway, you can follow that:

#views.py

```
def Category(request, slug):
    category_user = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    category_video = Video.objects.filter(category=category_user)
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    dict = {'category_user' : category_user, 'category_video' : category_video, 'categories' : categories}
    return render(request, 'categories.html', dict)
```

I just modified the capital of the "c" character in the filter of video model

#html

```
{% for video in category_video %} 
    {% for cats in video.category_set.all %}
        {{ cats.<fieldname> }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That doesnt work for me but get me to thought and i made it... so thank you so much :>

Comment: you are right, maybe I made a mistake here because I'm away from the code but a pleasure to give you a hint it's better than the complete help to the more understanding